# How to call batch script from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have one big batch script which sets bunch of environment variables. 
I want to call that batch script from powershell, that way I can get benefits of both i.e. enviorment variable set by my script and powershell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The idea comes from this blog post: [Nothing solves everything – PowerShell and other technologies](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/05/11/nothing-solves-everything-%e2%80%93-powershell-and-other-technologies/)

Here is my version of this script. It calls a batch file (or any *native* command) and propagates its environment:

---

UPDATE: Improved and better tested version of this script is here: [Invoke-Environment.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Invoke-Environment.ps1)

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Invokes a command and imports its environment variables.

.DESCRIPTION
    It invokes any cmd shell command (normally a configuration batch file) and
    imports its environment variables to the calling process. Command output is
    discarded completely. It fails if the command exit code is not 0. To ignore
    the exit code use the 'call' command.

.PARAMETER Command
        Any cmd shell command, normally a configuration batch file.

.EXAMPLE
    # Invokes Config.bat in the current directory or the system path
    Invoke-Environment Config.bat

.EXAMPLE
    # Visual Studio environment: works even if exit code is not 0
    Invoke-Environment 'call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"'

.EXAMPLE
    # This command fails if vsvars32.bat exit code is not 0
    Invoke-Environment '"%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"'
#>

param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]
    $Command
)

cmd /c "$Command > nul 2>&1 && set" | .{process{
    if ($_ -match '^([^=]+)=(.*)') {
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($matches[1], $matches[2])
    }
}}

if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    throw "Command '$Command': exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"
}
```

---

P.S. Here is the proposal to add similar capability to PowerShell: [Extend dot sourcing concept to cmd files](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/564858/extend-dot-sourcing-concept-to-cmd-files)

Comment: You may want to use just `$Command > nul 2>&1 && set` just in case `$Command` has a non-zero exit code but still changes the environment.

Comment: The linked 'improved and better tested' version didn't work for me, but copy pasting the script from this answer did.

Comment: Thank you for the alarm. Can you create an issue [there](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/issues) and describe your use case?

Comment: I haven't got an account there. I tried: Invoke-Environment '"%VS120COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"' -Force

Comment: Fixed (weird, cmd needs one extra space after /c). I cannot try with VS120COMNTOOLS now but with VS100COMNTOOLS it works fine.

Comment: so... if the batch file calls/runs other batch files, or if it branches and only sets certain environment variables depending on certain conditions, then this is not a complete solution and might miss or set values inappropriately? not complaining per se, just trying to verify my understanding of what it's doing

Comment: I'll add the security warning not to curl/wget anything from a public Git repo. Download the script and host it in a trusted place.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Comment: Yes, because either PowerShell or Microsoft removed the whole issue tracker resource.

Answer (score 26):

If you grab the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx), there is an Invoke-BatchFile command in it that runs the batch file but more importantly, it retains any environment variable modifications made by the batch file e.g.:

```
>Invoke-BatchFile 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat'
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
```

Comment: Notes to self, as per below, 
1.To install from the zip file on codeplex, right-click and a modal button, "unblock" appears; click it.
2.Unzip after unblocking and then place the folder in your modules location, as per $PSHome\Modules.
http://stam.blogs.com/8bits/2010/06/installing-powershell-community-extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to convert your batch script to PowerShell script? If you run the bat file, its is executed in separate session that doesn't modify PowerShell's env variables.

You can work with env variables very smoothly:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem env:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME                   xyz
ComSpec                        C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DXSDK_DIR                      D:\prgs\dev\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)\
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK               NO
HOMEDRIVE                      Z:
HOMEPATH                       \
...

PS> Get-Item env:path
Name  Value
----  -----
Path  c:\dev\CollabNet\SubversionClient;C:\Windows\system32;...
```

Or even (much shorter, returns only string):

```
PS> $env:path
c:\dev\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\Windows\system32;...
```

You can change the environment path like this:

```
PS> $env:path += ";c:\mydir"
```

And you can even set environment variables at machine level like this:

```
# fist arg = env variable name, second = value, third = level, available are 'Process', 'User', 'Machine'
PS> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('test', 'value', 'machine')
```

Answer (score 1):

@Roman Kuzmin's solution works great, but piping the command output to nul can kind of leave you in the dark. So I made a few tweaks to allow for the command output to display normally, and instead pipe the env vars to a temp file to read in afterwards:

```bsh
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]
    $Command
)
$VarsPath = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
cmd /c "$Command && set > $VarsPath"
if (-not $LASTEXITCODE) {
    Get-Content $VarsPath | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^([^=]+)=(.*)') {
            [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($matches[1], $matches[2])
        }
    }
}
Remove-Item $VarsPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a batch script from Powershell just by putting its name, but that won't help you. Environment variables set in the batch script will only be visible from *that batch and anything that batch runs*. Once the control returns back to Powershell the environment variables are gone. You could have the batch script run `set` at the end and then parse its output into your PSH environment variables, though.