# Powershell doesn't have the correct path info after the vsvars32.bat command

Tags: .net, powershell, environment-variables

With command prompt, I run `vsvars32` to run all the visual studio command line utilities (compiler, linker ...).

[image]

However, when I run the same thing with PowerShell, I can't run the utilities. What might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PowerShell for Visual Studio Command Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398136/use-powershell-for-visual-studio-command-prompt)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is in here: [Use PowerShell for Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4398136/323582)

Answer (score 5):

Running a batch file causes it to spawn its own process, which doesn't affect the powershell environment.  For a workaround, see: [How to call batch script from Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384814/how-to-call-batch-script-from-powershell)