# How to run batch file using powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run one batch file using powershell. It required property file to start the APP as without it is failing.

Below are the commands which i have tried but dint get success.

```
cmd.exe /c ' C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.bat -p C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.prop
```

or

```
& "C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.exe" "C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.prop"
```

or

```
& "C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.exe" C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.prop
```

Could someone suggest more on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call batch script from Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384814/how-to-call-batch-script-from-powershell)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use just

```
C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.bat -p C:\designer\5.7\bin\designer.prop
```

Your latter two examples should work as they are.

Answer (score 0):

*x.vbs file content following:*

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K CD **path** & **x.bat** **parameter**"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

*powershell script following :*

```
Start-Process x.vbs
```