# Exact command for starting a batch file by using powershell

Tags: batch-file, powershell, parameters

I know this question has been asked before and I found a thread on here which almost gives me the solution I need.

Here is the link: [How to run batch file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098167/how-to-run-batch-file-using-powershell)

But this only works when I write out the full path. For example:

`c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\start.bat -p c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\start.prop`

What I want to reach is a solution which accepts a path with parameters, like this one here:

`c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\start.bat -p c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\start.prop`

Whereas `$title` contains the name of my file which I am using in this case. I know that I can create another parameter for the `-p` command and I know that this works, but unfortunately when I try the same method for the first command I always get an error message.

I hope you guys know a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Invoke-Expression` could help here.
Just construct your path like you want it to be, for example:

```
$title = "file"
$path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\start.bat -p c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dcp_bearbeitet\$title\start.prop"
```

and then invoke it:

```
Invoke-Expression $path
```

Regards Paul

Comment: thank you, you saved my day. Until now I never knew what Invoke-Expression does, that is why I never tried it. I gave you the answer.