# Batch server ping and restart for a game

Tags: batch-file, server, ping, restart

Just looking for a correction/addition to this cannibalized restart code for (originally a Minecraft server, though that is not what it's used for now).

```
 @echo off
title Server Restarter
color 0A
cls
@%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 xxx.xxx.x.xx
pause

:start
Call Server.bat
cls
pause
```

This currently does a very simple job: calls `server.bat` and starts the server. It has none of the bells and whistles I'd like it to have though.
The output of ping is not functional at the moment.

The goal:

1. Ping to see if a specific IP (and maybe ports) are reachable.
2. If they are **not** reachable, close any current instances of **Server.exe**
3. Continue pinging **until** specific IP **is reachable.**
4. Once the IP **is** reachable, call `server.bat`

It needs to ping at intervals of ~30 seconds.

Some context for why it's needed:

The game server does not currently close its process regardless of it being online or not, it continues to run in the process window. That's why I need it close any current instances, else we just end up with multiples of the same server running.

The server is run from a local computer using direct IP connection, therefore if the local computer isn't connected to the internet, the server wont be reachable to anyone (obviously).  The intent for the `.bat` is to run continuously so even when the user isn't at the computer, it will take care of ensuring the server is online 24/7.

This will be a file I will want to make available to other server hosts who may want to use it to keep themselves online 24/7.

The port check will be to ensure the master server ports are reachable and the fault is/isn't on their side, this is not essential so if it's too much trouble, don't worry.

Inside "Server.bat":

```
@echo off
echo Server process starting
echo Ctrl+Alt+Del to Kill
Server.exe -batchmode -nographics
```

All of your assistance and comments are very much welcomed.  I tried to generalize this as much as possible to keep it simple, so it can be altered for anyone else who may find use for it with any application.

Comment: First off: you don't need the `@` in the `ping` command. Secondly, you can use `&` or `|` operator to detect if ping succeded or not. You can also try `%errorlevel%` variable.

Comment: @SteveFest Sorry, I don't quite understand, where/how would I use  `%errorlevel%` or `&` `|`

My level of batch understanding is unquestionably limited.

Comment: go to ss64.com/nt and you can find those out

Comment: @SteveFest I see, I may have not been clear enough, I apologize.
This is determining if it has successfully executed the ping command.
Not whether the return ping itself was successful.

E.g, sent packet x1 // received packet x1 = lost 0
or
sent packet x1 // did not receive packet x1 = lost 1

Comment: Well. alternatively, you can use a for loop to retrieve the command result, and you can determine if ping is successful(a failure ping comes with specific text, and you can check if ping result comes with such text.)

Comment: Note: I mean `for /f` loop

Comment: @SteveFest Thanks, this seems to be what I want, now it's trying to make it do a kind of IF not 100 then Call start.

I've got it working right (ish):
`set _ping_cmd=ping -n 1 XXX.XX.XX.XX

FOR /f "tokens=5 delims=(=" %%G IN ('%_ping_cmd% ^|find "100"') DO echo %Result% is [%%G] 
pause

:start
Call Server.bat
cls
pause`

The pause is just so I can see its readout, now all it needs is the &&/| | operator(s), because it will run Server.bat regardless of the result, but it is now correctly looking for the result of the ping.

Comment: In your `for` loop, you can try an `if` statement like so: if the result is not 100, start server.bat...

Comment: Or more precisely: `..."100"') DO if not %result% equ 100 call server.bat`

Comment: @SteveFest, I accidentally put the echo Result into %result% in my attempts to get it to respond to the readout, but quickly realized result isn't any kind of variable..

Instead I'm trying to get to use IF %%G equ 100 call Server.bat but that wont work either.

My current line looks like:
`FOR /f "tokens=5 delims=(=" %%G IN ('%_ping_cmd% ^|find "100"') DO echo Result is [%%G]`

Comment: What do you get if you `echo %%G`?

Comment: Echoing %%G after `DO echo Result is [%%G] displays " %G "

Comment: So you are comparing `100% loss` with `100`. That's incorrect, try to trim the result with `..delims=(= "` so that you will compare `100` with `100`.

Comment: Can't get to grips with delims and tokens, even with ss64.com
This is as far as I could trim it: https://i.gyazo.com/3d3ec415c87951ccc66eaa069dab02c7.png

Comment: Use variable substring and delayedexpansion. Put the following in the 2nd line of your file: `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. Then change your  `for` loop like so: http://imgur.com/WaBogqe

Comment: Note: you have to add the `if` statement after the two set statements.

Comment: @SteveFest
Okay, no result, this feels spaghetti-ish.
 must have missed something...
https://i.gyazo.com/7e8bb10ff75a239b3d0782e5d3465b81.png

Comment: Okay. Take a look in this completed script: http://imgur.com/2N4z8zh

Comment: @SteveFest Reporting it's unable to find 'Server.bat' which is odd, the Restart.bat is located in the same folder as Server.bat....
https://i.gyazo.com/fecd4b40abd6afee731ee22e46e93a82.png

Comment: Aw... My fault - :server.bat should be server.bat

Comment: @SteveFest Progress! However...
It runs fine when the IP is connectable (I assume because it's finding the '100', however, when the IP is not connectable (internet disconnected) it throws up an error.

The window to the left is non-connectable IP, on the right connectable IP.
https://i.gyazo.com/dc0a2e6816e85074948f50ee761f375e.png

Comment: The main problem is how you phase the `if` statement. At first, you can get `100%`, so why not try `if not "%%G" == "100%"? You don't need extra work then.

Comment: @SteveFest 
Attempted both here..

1. this one returns desired result of 100%, but has no function to start server.bat because of it.
https://i.gyazo.com/d45e26e16275ff3ef2e6689f53c0d68e.png

2. I attempted the IF statement you made.
https://i.gyazo.com/6264f0cba265dbd22a856ee397099d6f.png

You can try (if you wish) to run just a basic text file with :start [textfile].txt and if it manages to open a text file based on '100%' return of an IP address then you will know if it works.

Comment: **No!!!!** If statement doesn't work like that - read ss64

Comment: @SteveFest Have I got it here?
https://i.gyazo.com/34a9338ee50090b400f2592f53469203.png

Not running the server.bat however.

Comment: Ended up making this:
`@echo off 
title Server Restarter
color 0A
cls
:start
Echo Enter Server IP:
set /p ip=122.58.141.21

:ping
ping %ip% -n 1 || goto Starting
echo Ping was Successful to %ip% at %date% %time% 
goto set
if %ERRORLEVEL%==2 GOTO :EOF
cls
pause

:Starting
Echo Ping failed...
Start Server.bat || goto start
Echo Start Successful 
goto ping
pause`

Need to fix the... infinite looping...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're working on or with a Windows machine.  [Power Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) might be an option to write your scripts.  I came across this question after investigating [Test-Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) and [Test-NetConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/nettcpip/test-netconnection), which are both kind of like ping, and the latter lets you test if a port is open.  Not sure if there are batch file commands like those, but Power Shell lets you use most batch commands.  Both of these commands have tons of examples online, and are very easy to use in your use-case.

You probably want to have a `while (true)` loop running, and periodically do your ping/port checks.  That will satisfy your continual checking requirement.  [Start-Sleep](https://ss64.com/ps/start-sleep.html) is a cmdlet to let you pause your script, which you'll want to do in your forever loop.

You can [call batch files from Power Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384814/how-to-call-batch-script-from-powershell) ([another link from another good resource](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-run.html)), so that will let you reuse your existing scripts if you don't want to rewrite them in Power Shell.